# Working with two seperate git users (one repo for each user) from the same terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, gitlab

I am working on two different projects right now. One of them has a repo on Gitlab (this was the first project), and the other one has a repo on Github. I cloned both repos to my computer through the same terminal (Debian), and I use this termial for pretty much all repo interaction. Let the first name on my Gitlab user be "LabName".

My issue is that when I commit and push to the Github repo, it says on Github that "LabName" committed the changes, and that the project has 0 contributors. Is there a way to interact with my Github repo from my Github user, while still interacting with my Gitlab repo from my Gitlab user?

Comment: Configure user.name and user.email in both repositories, `git config user.email "your@email.com"` when you're in that repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as provided by Lasse V. Karlsen, was to use `git config user.name "your_username"` and `git config user.email "your@email.com"` each repo folder.

That is, you replace `your_username` with your Github username when in the Github repo, and with your Gitlab username when in your Gitlab repo, and repeat with `your@email.com`.

One can double check the username and email linked to a repo with the commands `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`.